# how to find existence and value of limit in multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, probability-limit-theorems

I was in maths class and i found a question interesting.
Find the limit of $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{2x}{x^2+x+y^2}$ if it exist.one of my friend did this question by transforming into polar coordinates and limit become $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{2\cos \theta}{r^2+\cos\theta}=\frac{2\cos \theta}{\cos\theta}=2$$ and argue the result that by the method above we sweeps out entire plane so we can do like this.But i did like this.I chose family of path given by $y^2=mx$ and put it in limit,then I got given limit as $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2}{x+m+1}=\frac{2}{m+1}$ which depends on m which means limit doesn't exist.What is correct??Is there any general method to find existence and value of limit.I know $\epsilon-\delta$ method but for that we must know the limit.Therefore how to find limit if we don't know that.Is polar conversion helps with this problem?If one find limit as existing from any method,how can we sure that we will find limit existing and unique in other method also?

Comment: Be careful with the very last computation, when you get 2, cause it does not work if $\theta = \pi/2$.

Comment: Yeah,right.Is there any general method for finding limit??

Comment: There is no general method. For the most part it is guess & verify.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit. Choose $x>0, m>0$, and $y=\sqrt{mx}$, then ${2x \over x^2 +x + y^2} = {2x \over x^2+(1+m)x} = { 2 \over x+(1+m)}$, and $\lim_ {x \downarrow 0} { 2 \over x+(1+m)} = { 2 \over 1+m}$. Since $m>0$ was arbitrary, there is no limit of the original function.

Your friend's technique would need to allow $\theta$ to be arbitrary as well, otherwise the limit is only taken over radial lines.

Comment: Is there any general method for finding the limit in multivariable calculus

Comment: Guess & verify!

Comment: no other method??I often feel like unable to do these kind of questions

Comment: There are lots of tricks, but no general techniques. Looking the the limit as you follow some path (as you did above) is a good start to reducing the problem to a single variable.

Comment: which tricks often uses?

Comment: any pdf file or link something like that??

Answer (score 1):

Your computation is right. If you substitute $y^2=mx$ you get that the limit depends on the path you take, hence it does not exist. Another way to show that it does not exist is taking the iterated limits:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{2x}{x^2+x+y^2}=2$$
while

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x}{x^2+x+y^2}=0$$

so it does not exist.

The error in your argument with polar coordinates is that the limit is not well-defined for all angles, namely $\theta=\pi/2+\pi k$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

A standard method to see if there is a limit is to do exactly what you did and make sure it holds for any arbitrary $r>0$ and angle $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$.

Also, trying to upperbound: Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and find $\delta$ such that for all $(x,y)$ with $\|(x,y)\| = \sqrt{x^2+ y^2} < \delta$ then

$$\left|\frac{2x}{x^2+x+y^2}\right| < \varepsilon$$
but the latter one might be tricky.

Comment: yeah,right.But i want to know whether there is a general method for finding the limit in multivariable calculus,which we can depend surely

Comment: but this one is for orgin,and we know the limit,what do we have to do if we don't know the limit?

Comment: I would say, first compute the iterated limits (which means one-variable caculus which you know well) then if you get the same value, try to prove that one IS the limit by either using polar coordinates or the epsilon-delta definition. You can always try different paths as you did to prove that the limit does not exist.

Comment: If the iterated limit is not 0, then you just can subtract the value to the function and prove that the limit is 0. I mean: imagine $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)=L$ then consider $g(x,y)=f(x,y)-L$ and prove that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} g(x,y) =0 $ which you know. If the limit is $\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} f(x,y)$, you can always transform it by doing this: $\lim_{(x-a,y-b)\to (0,0)} f(x,y) = \lim_{(z,w)\to (0,0)} f(z+a,w+b) $

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: Usually i find epsilon-delta method more difficult and i try maximum to avoid by that method,I don't doubt in that method,its like my last weapon.:).So if i use polar coordinate,how will i know there maybe some path as above where it doesn't exist,Can we use a method apart from epsilon-delta??

Comment: The polar coordinates is very nice. Other than that there is no standard and straightforward method, each function is a different world. I would even suggest you prove stronger conditions to get continuity, like proving differentiability (which implies continuity)

Comment: yeah,i didn't think that way,but if i got same answer in iterated limits and polartransformed limit,but limit doesn't exist(that can be possible)??

Comment: No no. If you use polar coordinates correctly and that gives you something, then that thing is the limit. In Your case, the polar coordinates were not helping cause you had a singularity for $\theta=\pi /2$. But if you try, let's say: $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3+y^4}{x^2+y^2}$ using polar coordinates now, you will get that the limit is 0.